# Why this kind of error occur when installing webpack

Tags: reactjs

npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! path E:\Program File\Node\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
npm ERR! dest E:\Program File\Node\npm.cmd
npm ERR! EEXIST: file already exists, cmd shim 'E:\Program File\Node\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js' -> 'E:\Program File\Node\npm.cmd'
npm ERR! File exists: E:\Program File\Node\npm.cmd
npm ERR! Remove the existing file and try again, or run npm
npm ERR! with --force to overwrite files recklessly.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Yesh Adithya\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-09-26T09_40_50_917Z-debug.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have already installed the package that you are trying to install again. There may be a version mismatch.
Try navigating to the node modules and delete the file and remove the entry in package.json
and try re-installing again.

Comment: It work when I am removing the entry in pakage.json and re-installing again.